# prove $\log_{10} (2)$ is irrational 

Tags: logarithms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [About irrational logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9141/about-irrational-logarithms)

Please help proving that $\log_{10}(2)$ is irrational.

Comment: I'm going to downvote this question based on the complete lack of information. You haven't said why you're interested, what context you're working in, or what you have tried.

Answer (score 12):

Hint: if $10^{a/b} = 2$ then $10^a = 2^b$.

Answer (score 3):

Prove by contradiction. So start by assuming

$$\log_{10}{2}=\frac{m}{n}$$, where $m$ and $n$ are integers.

$$10^\frac{m}{n}=2$$

$$10^m=2^n$$

and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Qwirk I wish you would not give such full responses to incomplete questions. Try giving a hint.

Comment: @a little don - noted, however think the hard work is still to come.

Answer (score 2):

We argue by contradiction. Suppose $\log_{10} 2 = \frac{p}{q}$ is rational with $q > p > 0$. Then $ 2^{q} = 10^{p} = 2^{p} \ 5^{p}$, so $2^{q - p} = 5^{p}$. Since $q > p$ and $p > 0$, it follows that $2^{q - p} \equiv 0 \mod 5$, which is impossible since no power of $2$ ends in $0$ or $5$. Hence $\log_{10} 2$ is irrational.

This method generalizes easily to prove the irrationality of many reals of the form $\log_{b} \ a$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: You didn't actually use gcd(p,q)=1, as far as I can see.