# Is $\ln n$ transcendental for all rational $n>1$?

Tags: logarithms, transcendental-numbers

I know that [$\ln n$ is transcendental for all integer $n>1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46497/is-lnn-transcendental-for-all-integer-n-1). But does this still hold for non-integer rational values of $n>1$? For example, is $\ln 1.5$ transcendental?

EDIT: Somehow managed to overlook the fact that cases like $\ln e=1$ are not transcendental :P The question has been revised to only include rational numbers $n$.

Comment: $\ln e$, for example, is not transcendental.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, what about:
$$
\ln(e^2)=2
$$
And $2$ is certanly not trancendental.

---

It is however possible to restrict the values of $n$ further than integers. By the [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), any algebraic number $\alpha\ne1$ has $\ln\alpha$ as trancendental.

Since any rational number is algebraic, and $1.5$ is a rational number, $\ln1.5$ is trancendental.

Comment: >.< Thanks for pointing it out, and the question's been edited to be clearer.

Comment: @user3932000 I have updated the answer to restrict further which values are trancendental.

Comment: So yes, $\ln 1.5$ is transcendental?

Comment: @user3932000 Yes

Comment: [WolframAlpha is telling me that it doesn't know whether $\ln 1.5$ is transcendental or not.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+ln%281.5%29+transcendental) What does this mean?

Comment: @user3932000 It means that wolfram alpha acts weird when given decimal numbers, as a fraction however: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+ln%283%2F2%29+transcendental

Answer (score 1):

$\qquad$ This is probably the equivalent of nuking a mosquito, but if $\ln x$ would be transcendental for every value of *x*, then the logarithmic function would be discontinuous in every point, since the [transcendental numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) form a [dense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set), but not continuous, subset of the reals. However, we know that the natural logarithm *is* continuous, hence contradiction. $($As for the amended version of the initial post, the answer is yes$)$.