# Can an irrational number raised to an irrational power be rational?

Tags: irrational-numbers

Can an irrational number raised to an irrational power be rational?

If it can be rational, how can one prove it?

Comment: The classic answer involves $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$. See for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_excluded_middle#Examples.

Comment: http://www.math.purdue.edu/pow/fall2011/pdf/problem10.pdf; solution at http://www.math.purdue.edu/pow/fall2011/pdf/solution10.pdf .

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem

Answer (score 193, accepted):

There is a classic example here. Consider $A=\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$. Then $A$ is either rational or irrational. If it is irrational, then we have $A^\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2}^2=2$.

Comment: And one of the most beautifully frustrating ones, since even at the end we do not know what proved our theorem!

Comment: That's awesome.  I've never seen a proof quite like that one.

Comment: This is especially noteworthy because it's an extremely simple **existence** proof:  we proved that such a number *exists* without proving what that number is!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is $A$ rational or irrational? (Just in the case we'd like to find a constructive proof of this example.)

Comment: @PetrPudlák The [Gelfond-Schneider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) theorem establishes that $A$ is transcendental (and in particular, irrational).

Comment: sorry if this is really obvious, but I think don't get it. So raising to irrationals always gives rationals?

Comment: @Pinocchio: No - "usually", in a handwaving sense, an irrational number raised to an irrational power is irrational, but sometimes it is rational.

Comment: I stared at this excellent example blankly for 5 minutes before realising you mean "If A is irrational then we have $A^{\sqrt2}=2$ is rational instead."

Comment: What if I told you I don't accept the law of excluded middle?

Comment: [More detailed explanation for those having trouble following this very terse proof.](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51618.html)

Comment: Sir what if $A$ is rational? Then it gives required number.

Comment: @6005 even after reading that, im still struggling. what is the signifiance behind the last sentence?

Answer (score 121):

Yes, it can,  $$   e^{\log 2} = 2    $$

**Summary of edits**: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are *algebraic* and irrational, then 
$\alpha^\beta$ is not only irrational but transcendental.

Looking at your other question, it seems worth discussing what happens with square roots, cube roots, algebraic numbers in general. I heartily recommend Irrational Numbers by Ivan Niven, [NIVEN](https://www.maa.org/ebusppro/DynamicSearch/ProductDetailsAdvancedSearch/tabid/176/ProductId/947/Default.aspx).

So, the more precise question is about numbers such as $$ {\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2}.$$ For quite a long time the nature of such a number  was not known. Also, it is worth pointing out that such expressions have infinitely many values, given by all the possible values of the expression
$$ \alpha^\beta = \exp \, ( \beta \log \alpha )   $$ 
in  $\mathbb C.$ The point is that any specific value of $\log \alpha$ can be altered by $2 \pi i,$ thus altering $\beta \log \alpha$ by $2 \beta \pi i,$ finally altering the chosen interpretation of  $\alpha^\beta.$ Of course, if $\alpha$ is real and positive, people use the principal branch of the logarithm, where $\log \alpha$ is also real, so just the one meaning of $\alpha^\beta$ is intended.

Finally, we get to the Gelfond-Schneider theorem, from Niven page 134: If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic numbers with $\alpha \neq 0, \; \alpha \neq 1$ and $\beta$ is not a real rational number, then any value of $\alpha^\beta$ is transcendental.

In particular, any value of $$ {\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2}$$ is transcendental, including the "principal" and positive real value that a calculator will give you for $\alpha^\beta$ when both $\alpha, \; \beta$ are positive real numbers, defined as usual by $ e^{\beta \log \alpha}$.

There is a detail here that is not often seen. One logarithm of $-1$ is $i \pi,$ this is Euler's famous formula
$$  e^{i \pi} + 1 = 0.$$ And $\alpha = -1$ ***is*** permitted in Gelfond-Schneider. Suppose we have a positive real, and algebraic but irrational $x,$ so we may take $\beta = x.$ Then G-S says that 
$$  \alpha^\beta = (-1)^x = \exp \,(x \log (-1)) = \exp (i \pi x) = e^{i \pi x} = \cos \pi x + i \sin \pi x  $$ is transcendental. Who knew?

Comment: Ba-dum-chhhh.  Short and sweet.

Comment: It's well known that e is irrational, but what about $\log 2 = \ln 2$?

Comment: @Myself: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15285/is-the-natural-log-of-n-rational

Comment: OTOH, proving that $e$ and $\log 2$ are irrational is not trivial.

Comment: @myself: if $\ln 2 = a/b$ then $e$ a solution of $x^a-2^b=0$.  But $e$ is transcendental (not algebraic) so $a/b$ cannot be rational.

Comment: The phrase "such numbers have infinitely many values" is a contradiction in terms. A value is a number, so every number has (is) a unique value. You mean infinitely many values can be assigned to the _expression_ in question. Although in this case (positive real base) one usually does consider the value uniquely defined. Would you say that $-\exp(-2\pi^2)$ is a possible value of $e^{i\pi}$ because $1+2i\pi$ is a possible value of $\ln e$?

Comment: The link to Niven's article does not work anymore :/

Comment: @BarbaraKwarc here is their page http://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/irrational-numbers  available ebook or paperback. Also some preview at that site

Comment: *THUD* <-- That was the sound of my head bashing against the paywall :q But thanks anyway...

Answer (score 15):

If $r$ is any positive rational other than  $1$, then for all but countably many positive  reals $x$  both $x$ and $y = \log_x r = \ln(r)/\ln(x)$ are irrational (in fact transcendental), and $x^y = r$.

Answer (score 7):

For example:
$$\sqrt{2}^{2\log_2 3} = 3$$

$\bf{Added:}$ Let's use [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) and show that there exist $\alpha$, $\beta$ transcendental with $\alpha^\beta$ rational.  Indeed, consider the $\alpha>1$ satisfying $\alpha^{\alpha} = 3$. Then $\alpha$ is not rational ( easy to see), and hence it must be transcendental.

Consider the bijection $[1, \infty) \ni x \overset{\phi}{\mapsto} x^x \in [1, \infty)$. It is not hard to check that if $r$ and $\phi(r)$ are  rational,  then $r$ is an integer. Hence we have lots of example as above.

Comment: This looks quite a lot like the accepted answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449431/rational-number-to-the-power-of-irrational-number-irrational-number-true?rq=1).

Comment: it should be as common as the $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ 'trick"

Comment: I like this since $\sqrt 2^{\log_2(3)} = \sqrt 3$, thus showing that irrational to irrational power can also be irrational.

Answer (score 6):

Let me expand orangeskid's answer, both because I think it teaches us something useful, and it might be the easiest elementary proof for this question.

The proof that $ \sqrt{2} $ is irrational is well-known, so I will not repeat it here.

But there's a proof just as simple showing that $ \log 3 / \log 2 $ is irrational.  Suppose on contrary that $ \log 3 / \log 2 = p / q $ where p and q are integers.  Since $ 0 < \log 3 / \log 2 $, we can choose $ p $ and $ q $ both as positive integers.  The equality then rearranges to $ 3^q = 2^p $.  But here, the left hand side is odd and the right hand side is even, so we get a contradiction.

That gives a positive answer to the original question:
$$
\big(\sqrt{2}\big)^{2 \log 3 / \log 2} = 3
$$

Thanks to Rand al'Thor, [who mentioned this problem in SE chat and thus inspired this answer](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57180379#57180379).

Answer (score 5):

Consider, for example, $2^{1/\pi}=x$, where $x$ should probably be irrational but $x^\pi=2$. More generally, 2 and $\pi$ can be replaced by other rational and irrational numbers, respectively.

Comment: How do you know your $x$ is irrational?

Comment: Actually, I just realized that my example is a specific case of robert's answer. In any case, @GEdgar, I'm quite sure that $x$ is irrational but as long as I (or someone else) does not prove it I'll keep a softer phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

$e^{\ln(2)}$, when $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm.

Hermite proved that $e$ is transcendental.

[https://web.math.utk.edu/~freire/m400su06/transcendence%20of%20e.pdf](https://web.math.utk.edu/%7Efreire/m400su06/transcendence%20of%20e.pdf)

$e$ is a real number. If it were rational, it would be the solution of some $ax+b=0$ for integers $a$ and $b$, which is impossible per Hermite. So $e$ is irrational.

To prove $\ln(2)$ is irrational, we assume coprime integers $p$ and $q$ such that $\frac{p}{q}=\ln(2)$

As $e^{\ln(2)}=2$, we can substitute $\frac{p}{q}=\ln(2)$ to get

$$e^{\frac pq}=2 $$

Raise both sides to the $q$th power.

$$e^p=2^q$$

Now, let

$$x^p-2^q=0$$

This is a binomial equation in terms of $x$ with degree $p$, and $e$ would be a solution, contradicting Hermite above. So $\ln(2)$ is irrational.