# Can anyone give me a counterexample to this statement?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Statement:  Let $n$ and $m$ be two irrational numbers. Then $n^m$ is always irrational.

I think this statement is correct, otherwise can someone give me a counterexample?

Thanks!

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104119/can-an-irrational-number-raised-to-an-irrational-power-be-rational).

Comment: @DannyCheuk I modified your edit because it uses very nonstandard notation.

Comment: Cool, I was actually struggling to decide what symbol to use for irrational numbers

Answer (score 11):

A simple counterexample:
$$e^{\ln 2}$$

Answer (score 7):

Exactly one of these is a counterexample: $√3^{√2}$, $(√3^{√2})^{√2} = 3$.

Hint: What happens if $√3^{√2}$ is rational? What happens if it's irrational?

Comment: Very nice example! I'd add "Hint" to this. +1

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample:

Let $a$ be a number such that $\log a\notin\mathbb{N}:e^{\log a}\in\mathbb{Q} $

Answer (score 2):

$x = 2^\sqrt2 $, $y=1/\sqrt2$ , $x^y=2$