# Examples of $r^{\sqrt{2}}$ as an irrational number, for real numbers $0<r<1$

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

After I've read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456176/prove-that-sqrt2-sqrt2-is-an-irrational-number-without-using-a-theorem) in this Mathematics Stack Exchange, and I tried some failed calculations, I've typed in Wolfram Alpha [online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com) the code *(sqrt(2)/2)^sqrt(2)* to get as output that also this number is transcendent, and thus irrational.

Before this calculation with Wolfram Alpha, as I am saying was a curiosity that I was asking myself if it is possible deduce or are known some cases for which one can state that  $r^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational, when $$0<r<1$$ is a real number. The only calculations that I did were, on assumption that $p$ and $q$ are positive integers with $\gcd(p,q)=1$,  from $$r^{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{p}{q}$$ that 
$$\sqrt{2}\log r=\log p-\log q.\tag{1}$$
taking logarithms. And additionally if we presume, by contradiction, that $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number,  I can write the condition $$\frac{P}{Q}\log r=\log p-\log q,\tag{2}$$
where $P$ and $Q$ are positive integers satisfying $\gcd(P,Q)=1$.

But $(1)$ neither $(2)$ don't say nothing to me.

> **Question.** Imagine that a friend ask me for a reasoning to get examples of irrational numbers of the form $$r^{\sqrt{2}},$$ when the real number $r$ runs on the set $0<r<1$. What is the reasoning that I should be tell my friend? If we want to create simple examples of irrational number of the form $r^{\sqrt{2}}$, 
>    what are simple requirements/conditions that need to be met those real numbers $0<r<1$? Of course if you need theorems of the kind of Gelfond-Schneider's theorem, or a different approach you can combine with these statements in your discussion to get some examples using a mathematical reasoning. If you know literature you can reference it. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Did you look at the [mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138247/prove-that-sqrt2-sqrt2-is-an-irrational-number-without-using-a-theorem) linked to in the question you posted?  Seems to do a pretty good job of answering....

Comment: Thanks then this afternoon I will try to understand the answer of Mark Sapir, and other comments in Math Overflow. With my Question I am asking what should be a discussion of  simple cases $r^{\sqrt{2}}$ being irrational, and of course using the theorems from the literature about transcendent numbers. Many thanks for your attention @lulu

Comment: IMHO, if there's no restriction on $x$ other than a real number, things get easy. Let $b$ be an irrational number (infinitely many such numbers) in the interval $(0,1)$ such that $r^{\sqrt(2)}=b$, you can express $r$ with the logarithm function.

Comment: Many thanks also for your contribution @Huang

Comment: You can choose every algebraic irrational number $r$ with $0<r<1$. As pointed out below the Gelfond-Schneider-theorem guarantees that $r^{\sqrt{2}}$ will be transcendental, hence irrational. You could , for example, choose the golden-ratio-number $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$

Comment: Many thanks for your help, feel free to add an answer with your remarks, as a formalized proof @Peter

Comment: @user243301 I cannot prove the Gelfond-Schneider-Theorem, I only apllied it. And the answer would not contain much more info than the answer already given.

Comment: Of course, I am saying the application of such theorem and your example @Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gelfond-Schneider-theorem mentioned by Jack allows a more general choice for $r$ :

> For every algebraic irrational $r$ with $0<r<1$, the number $r^{\sqrt{2}}$ is transcendental, hence irrational.

A particular cute choice is the golden-ratio-number $\phi=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is a trascendental number from the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), hence its reciprocal $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{\sqrt{2}}$
is clearly an irrational number.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the example.