# Proving that $a^{b}$ is rational (Elementary number theorey)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

Prove that there exist irrational numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^{b}$ is rational.

What i tried

Prove by contradiction

I assume the statement

For all  rational numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^{b}$ is rational

Since $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be rational, they can be expressed in the form

$$a=\frac{c}{d}$$

$$b=\frac{x}{y}$$

then $$a^{b}=(\frac{c}{d})^\frac{x}{y}$$

From here we know that $$(\frac{c}{d})^\frac{x}{y}$$

doesent necessarily have to be rational as can be seen from the example if $x=1$ and $y=2$, hence $a^{b}$ dosent necessarily have to be rational. But from our assumption, we assumed that $a^{b}$ have to be rational. Hence a contradiction and thus proving the original statement. Is my proof correct. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104119/can-an-irrational-number-raised-to-an-irrational-power-be-rational and http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/irrat.shtml

Comment: If you "know that $(c/d)^{x/y}$ doesn't have to be rational" and you also give an example, why don't you give just an counterexample as proof?

Comment: I hate to tell this, but your argument is almost totally unrelated to the claim, as it begins with an erroneous contraposition

Answer (score 7):

This is a classic problem:

Note that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

If $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is *rational* then you are done.

If $\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$ is *irrational*, then $(\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2})^\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}^2 = 2$ is rational, and satisfies the desired constraint of "irrational to the power of an irrational... is rational."

Answer (score 2):

This is a very popular problem. Here is the solution.

If $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is rational, you are done. Otherwise, it is irrational.

Then take $$\left( \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}} \right)^{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}= \sqrt{2}^2=2$$
which is rational.

In any case, you have that there exist some two irrational numbers $a,b$ such that $a^b$ is rational.

Comment: Oh Thanks but is my way of doing also considered correct?

Comment: No, your argument is totally incorrect.

Comment: Oh but why is my argument incorect?

Comment: As it is stated in the comments above, in order to prove your statement by contradiction, you should begin assuming that "for all $a,b>0$ irrational, $a^b$ is irrational" and get some contradiction. In other words, you made a mistake in taking the negation of your statement.