# How can I prove $\sqrt{2} ^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, irrational-numbers

I am learning proofs and a question was posed which asked us to prove that $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational. They mentioned this - *Hint:* try using the log10 function...

I tried my hand at the proof by contradiction. Assuming $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is rational. Hence,

$\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{p}{q} \implies \big({\frac{p}{q}}\big)^{\sqrt{2}} = 2$

Can I now say, that we know that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, but $\frac{p}{q}$ and $2$ are rational;

If $a$ is rational and $b$ is irrational, $a^b$ must be irrational. *(1)

In our case $a^b = 2$ which is rational: a contradiction to our original assumption.

This is just tomfoolery on my part. I don't know if *(1) is even true or not; how can I approach such a problem?

Comment: Your statement is incorrect about irrational powers of rational numbers: let $a=1$. In fact, it is possible to take an irrational power of an irrational number and recover a rational number.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this without using some fairly advanced mathematics.

Comment: I don't know who'd pose this... See the first answer and the comments [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104119/can-an-irrational-number-raised-to-an-irrational-power-be-rational).

Answer (score 4):

The irrationality of $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is a trivial consequence of the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).

Comment: That is to say, a trivial consequence of a highly nontrivial theorem.