# Will irrational exponents always yield irrational results?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, irrational-numbers

Earlier today in my calculus class my professor asked for an estimate value of $4^\sqrt{2}$. Although that is easy if you just say that $\sqrt{2} \simeq 1.41$ and proceed with $4^{1.41} = 4^{\frac{141}{100}} = \sqrt[100]{4^{141}}$ and so on I couldn't stop wondering if, since $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$, does $4^{\sqrt{2}} \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ as well?

In a more generic sense, is it true that:

$$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \hspace{5pt} \colon \hspace{5pt} x^y\in\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$$

How may I prove (or disprove) it?

Comment: If you believe $\log 3 / \log 2$ is irrational, then $2^{\log 3 / \log 2 = 3$ is rational.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/104121/58818

Comment: Consider $q={\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2}$ and $q^{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: At least one of ${\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2}$ and $\left({\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2}\right)^{\sqrt 2}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: What is your definition of $x^b$ if $b$ is irrational?

Comment: @BrianTung Good question, I don't know.

Comment: In an informal sense, note that $f(x) = x^b$ for most values of $b$ (and under a typical definition) varies continuously between $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, and thus must pass through a countably infinite number of values $x$ for which $f(x)$ is a rational value.  However, this would generally not constitute a proof.

Comment: @BrianTung Nice. Is there a rigorous proof?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments give you counterexamples, including the classic one mentioned by Dave L. Renfro.

A general theorem in that direction is the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem):

> If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic numbers with $a \ne 0,1$ and $b$ irrational, then $a^b$ is a transcendental number.

Note that every transcendental number is irrational.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. For example take $$a^{\log_a(x)}=x$$ Take now $a$ rational such that $\log_a(x)$ don't be rational for $x$ rational.

However the irrational $\log_a(x)$ must be trascendental because if it is algebraic $\ne 0,1$ then x must be trascendental (Gelfond- Schneider theorem. Applying this same theorem we know that $\log_a(x)$ is trascendental for $x$ rational and distinct of $a^r$ with $r$ rational)