# Prove or disprove that there is a rational number $x$ and an irrational number $y$ such that $x^y$ is irrational.

Tags: proof-writing, exponentiation, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

In solving the following problem: Prove or disprove that there is a rational number $x$ and an irrational number $y$ such that $x^y$ is irrational. I let $x=2$ and $y = \sqrt 2$, so that $x^y = 2^\sqrt 2$.

Why is this not enough? How come I have to go through the case whether $x^y = 2^\sqrt 2$ is rational?

If $2^\sqrt 2$ is rational then let $x = 2^\sqrt 2$, and $y = \sqrt 2 / 4$

$x^y = (2^\sqrt 2)^{\sqrt 2 /4} = 2^{(\sqrt 2*\sqrt 2) /4} = 2^{2/4} = 2^{1/2} = \sqrt 2$ (previous value for y that was established as irrational.

Comment: And *how do you know* that $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational?

Comment: Elliott and @Zeekless:  Oh... it isn't rational.

Comment: If it were rational (which it isn't, but you don't know that for sure), then you'd have to go with $\left(2^\sqrt2\right)^\sqrt2$

Comment: @IvanNeretin:  What do you mean by "then you'd have to go with..."?

Comment: @David G. Stork, you misunderstand the question. Your last edit of the title is wrong.

Comment: Feel free to fix the title... and hopefully clarify what is really at issue.

Comment: It is often easier to prove that an irrational number of a certain form exists by indirect logic (considering alternatives).  I suspect you may have been given a hint along that line.

Comment: The question is about whether there *exists* a rational $x$ and an irrational $y$ such that $x^y$ is irrational.  That means you either find such an $x$, $y$, such that $x^y$ is irrational. (This only requires that for some rational $x$, there exists an irrational $y$ such $x^y$ is irrational. It does not necessarily mean that $x = 2$, $y= \sqrt 2$ must be irrational.

Comment: The more usual question is to show that there are irrational $a,b$ such that $a^b$ is rational.  Something being irrational is common but often hard to prove, like for $2^{\sqrt 2}$.  It is irrational, but I don't know an easy proof.  You have tried to display an example for your question, but have not supplied any proof that it is irrational.  The [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) says it is transcendental but I have never seen the proof.

Comment: Whatever is the case, @Ross, about what is a more usual question, doesn't seem to apply to this question, so I don't know why you had to include your first sentence.  It is irrelevant to this question, no?  The rest of your comment is spot on!

Comment: @jordan_glen:  I included it because I thought OP might have some of that question mixed in with this one.  It was prompted be a comment that I thought was from OP but was not.

Comment: @RossMillikan  I understand now.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear, so it doesn't matter that $2^ \sqrt2 $ is irrational or not, I know that $\sqrt 2$ is (because I set $^0y$) so as long as I can show that $x^y$ can result in a known irrational number, I've satisfied the proof? So similarly if I were to set $ ^0 y = \sqrt 3 $ or $^0y = \sqrt 5$ in order to show that $x^y$ is irrational I'd need to be able to show some combination of $x^y$ that result in what I set for $^0y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{I}$ denote the set of irrational numbers.

Function $f : \mathbb{I} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto 2^x$ is an injection.

$\mathbb{I}$ is uncountable $\Rightarrow$ image of $f$ is uncountable.

The set of rational numbers is countable $\Rightarrow$ image of $f$ contains something more than rationals.

There exist such irrational $x$ that $2^x$ is irrational.

Comment: See for example$2^{\log_2(\sqrt3)}=\sqrt3$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prove the statement consider first that for positive rational $a$ and real $b$ we have that $a^b$ is a continuous function of $b$ and given a positive real number $x$ we have $x=a^b$ when $\log x = b \log a$ or $b =\frac {\log x}{\log a}$ where we can take logarithms to any sensible base. (Note that $a=1$ is a special case here, so we avoid choosing $a=1$ when we have a choice).

Now the expressions $a^b$ where $a\in \mathbb Q^+; b\in \mathbb Q$ are countable and we can choose $x\in \mathbb R^+$ which is neither in the set of such expressions nor in $\mathbb Q$ (the union of two countable sets is countable). $x$ is irrational and is not expressible in the form $a^b$ with both $a$ and $b$ rational - so we choose a positive rational $a\neq 1$ and the corresponding $b$ must be irrational.

This is a non-constructive proof, which shows that there will be lots of examples.

Comment: $2^{\log_2(\sqrt3)}=\sqrt3$

Answer (score 0):

$$2^{\log_2(\sqrt3)}=\sqrt3$$

there are several proofs that the square roots of $3$ are irrational.

I posted a proof here.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4852744/928654

$$\log_2(\sqrt3)=\log_2(3)/2$$

If $log_2(3)$ were rational, there must be positive integers p/q such that $p/q=\log_2(3)$. (Remember that both $2$ and $3$ are greater than $1$.)

$$2^{log_2(3)}=2^{p/q}=3$$

$$2^p=3^q$$

All positive integer powers of 2 are even, and all positive integer powers of 3 are odd. We thus concluded that an even number equals an odd number- a contradiction. So $\log_2(3)$ is irrational, $\log_2(3)/2=\log_2({\sqrt3})$ is irrational, and we can conclude:

that there is a rational number  and an irrational number 
such that $^$ is irrational.

Comment: Another example is $2^{1/\ln(2)}$. This yields the base of the natural logarithm, which is irrational. 

$\ln(2)$ sole real value is irrational for the reasons listed in this answer.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4862041/928654