# There exists an irrational number $x$ such that $x^2$ is rational

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to prove or disprove this statement.
I am stuck on which method to use to solve this.
I can chose from direct, contra positive and contradiction

Comment: How about $\sqrt 2$?

Comment: direct proof is best I think.

Comment: A better and well known question is whether there is an irrational number $a$ such that $a^{\sqrt{2}}$ is rational.

Comment: @JCAA $a=\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$. This can be proven by exhaustion/cases.

Comment: @Pendronator: I know the answer to that problem for about $50$ years. As I said, it is a well known problem.

Comment: @JCAA do you have a reference for a proof for this statement? A quick google search as not clear for me.

Comment: @IntegrateThis: Search for Gelfond-Schneider theorem.

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104119/can-an-irrational-number-raised-to-an-irrational-power-be-rational

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.${}{}{}$

Comment: That's about as direct as you can get XD

Answer (score 1):

If $p$ is a prime then $\sqrt{p}$ is irrational, and moreover $(\sqrt{p})^2 = p$ is an integer.