# Does my proof of the irrationality of $\ln(2)$ hold up?

Tags: solution-verification, logarithms, irrational-numbers, rationality-testing, eulers-number-e

At first, I thought that proving the irrationality of $\ln(2)$ was so easy that it was trivial. However, someone in the comments of the $115$ vote answer at [Can an irrational number raised to an irrational power be rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104119/can-an-irrational-number-raised-to-an-irrational-power-be-rational) said that "OTOH, proving that e and log2 are irrational is not trivial." (Ihf said this). Thus, I decided to give it a so to see how difficult it is.

First, we assume that $\ln(2)$ is rational and can thus be written as the fraction $\frac{m}{n}$ with integers $m,n$ and $m$ and $n$ in lowest terms, meaning that $\gcd(m,n)$ $=1$. So we have that $$\ln(2) = \frac{m}{n}  \implies$$
$$2 = e^\frac{m}{n}  \implies$$ $$2^n = e^m $$

Since $n$ is an integer $2^n$ is an integer as well. For $\frac{m}{n}$ to be a valid fraction, we need $m$ to be an integer as well. However, since $m$ must be an integer, $e^m$ cannot be an integer because it is only an integer when we have $e^{\ln(a)}$ for some natural number $a$, but we know that $\ln(a)$ can't be an integer, with exception of $\ln(1) = 0$, but $m$ isn't $0$ because that would make our fraction $0$. Thus $2^n$ is an integer, while $e^m$ isn't, which is a contradiction. Thus our initial assumption that $\ln(2)$ is rational and can be written in lowest terms as $\frac{m}{n}$ is false, meaning that $\ln(2)$ is irrational. This proof seemed too easy, what did I do wrong?

Comment: A lot of silent work is being done by "$e^m$ cannot be an integer . . ." and thereabouts. I agree that this is a nontrivial result.

Comment: e^m = $\sum_{k \geq 0} \dfrac{m^k}{k!}$ how can you tell this sum is an integer ? I can't see that unless I have hawk's eye

Comment: How do you know $log(a)$ is only an integer for $a=1$?

Comment: How do you know that $\ln(a)$ is not an integer for $a \neq 1$?

Comment: You want to use the theorem that $e$ is transcendental.

Comment: @ILoveMath I said it isn't an integer. Didn't I?

Comment: You said it, but you didn't justify that claim.

Answer (score 3):

The proof can be streamlined in the following way. Suppose that $\log 2=m/n$ for two coprime integers $m$ and $n$. Then,
$$
e^{m/n}=2 \implies e^m=2^n \, .
$$
Hence, $e$ would be a root of the polynomial
$$
x^m-2^n=0 \, .
$$
But this would imply that $e$ is algebraic, which is untrue. Hence, $\log 2$ is irrational.

Comment: Thats circular reasoning, you used the fact that $e$ is transcedental to prove that it is irrational, but for $e$ to be transcedental, it had to be proven irrational first, otherwise if it were rational it would be the root of an equation $px = q$

Comment: @SomeGuy: I don't understand what part of my proof you think is circular. I'm using the fact that $e$ is transcendental to show that $\log 2$ is irrational, not that $e$ is irrational.

Comment: Oh nevermind, you're good @Joe