# Proof that $\ln(3) / \ln(2)$ is transcendental?

Tags: solution-verification, logarithms, transcendental-numbers

I was trying to figure out if $\ln(3)/\ln(2)$ is transcendental, when I found [this post by b_jonas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104119/can-an-irrational-number-raised-to-an-irrational-power-be-rational)

> But there's a proof just as simple showing that $\log 3/\log 2$  is
> irrational. Suppose on contrary that $\log 3/\log 2 = p/q$  where p and q are
> integers. Since $0< \log 3 / \log 2$ , we can choose p  and q  both as positive
> integers. The equality then rearranges to $3^q = 2^p$ . But here, the left
> hand side is odd and the right hand side is even, so we get a
> contradiction.

that demonstrates the expression is not rational. With that clue it seems fairly easy to deduce that the expression is also transcendental. Here is how my argument goes:

Suppose there is a number $k$ such that $ 2^k = 3 \, $ then $\ln(2^k) = \ln(3) = \ln(2)*k \Rightarrow k =\ln(3)/ \ln(2) $. By the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) $2^k $ should be transcendental if $k \neq 0,1$ is an algebraic irrational but $2^k = 3$, so k cannot be an algebraic irrational and it has already been demonstrated that $k$ is not an algebraic rational, so $\ln(3)/\ln(2)$ must be transcendental.

Is that correct?

If it is correct, it seems to follow that $ \ln(x) / \ln(y) $ is transcendental if $x$ and $y$ are integers with different parities, $(x,y \neq 0,1)$. (Later this extended to include the case where $x$ and $y$ are rational numbers with a few exceptions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks correct to me, and I think it generalizes to $\ln(a)/\ln(b)$ being transcendental for any positive integers $a,b$ that admit no solution to $a^p=b^q$ for positive integers $p,q$.

Whether such a pair $p,q$ exists can be determined from the prime factorization of $a,b$. The pair exists if and only if the ratio between the powers of each prime is the same.

For example if $a=2^65^9$ and $b=2^45^6$ then since $6/4=9/6$ a pair exists, namely $a^2=b^3$.

If $a=3^65^8$ and $b=3^45^4$ then since $6/4\neq8/4$ no pair exists and $\ln(a)/\ln(b)$ is transcendental.

Comment: Your first example is interesting because it can be written as $a=2^63^05^9 7^011^0$ and so on and $b=2^4 3^05^67^011^0$ and since $6/4=0/0=9/6=0/0=0/0$ a pair exists. It seems 0/0 can be used as a wildcard here. :-) Your 2nd example is an example of a=odd and b=odd resulting in a transcendental. We can also construct examples of a=odd and b=odd being rational, eg. $a=9=2^03^2$ and $b=3=2^03^1$ because $0/0=2/1$:-) or $\ln(9) / \ln(3)= \ln(3^2)\ln(3) =2*\ln(3)/ln(3)=2$ which is rational. It seems your method can determine the transcendence of $\ln(x)/ \ln(y)$ for any positive integers x and y.

Comment: @KDP It’s not really using 0/0 as a wildcard, if you take any any two natural numbers there will always be a prime p that’s not a prime factor of either. Then you can add the factor $p^0$ to the prime factorization of both numbers.