# Can a rational number be represented by a combination of irrational numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Any real number is some power of $e$ (because $\ln(x)$ has values in the range $(-\infty , + \infty)$.

> Say, $5$ is a rational number. So there is some $x$ which makes $\exp(x)= 5$.
>
> 1. What is $x$? rational , irrational?
> 2. A power of $e$  leads to $5$, Will it be an infinite series converging to the value $5$?
> 3. Can a combination of irrational number result into a rational number?

Comment: I don't really know what the question is, but $\ln(5)$ is irrational, a consequence of the fact that $e$ is transcendental.  If $e^{p/q}=5$, then $e^p=5^q$.  Slightly more generally, if $e^x$ is rational, then $x$ is irrational.  Related question where you'll find a much more general statement: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15285/is-the-natural-log-of-n-rational

Comment: What @Jonas said. Regarding *Can a combination of irrational number(s) ... result into a rational number?*, consider $\pi+(42-\pi)$.

Comment: $(1/2 + \pi) + (1/2 - \pi) = 1$.

Comment: @Jonas, also $x$ must be nonzero.

Comment: Also, if x is rational, then e^x is irrational. This statement is different to Jonas'.

Comment: @sdevve: Good point, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Adam: it is equivalent (via contrapositive).

Comment: oh yeah. You're right

Answer (score 2):

(When he was 12) George Bergman proved that any integer can be represented by a finite sum of integral powers of the golden ratio (irrational number), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio_base.  And any rational can be written as the ratio of two integers.

Answer (score 1):

What precisely do you mean by a "combination of irrational number[s]"?

Obviously $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ are both irrational, and if "combining" them allows for the operation of addition, then just observe the sum is the rational number $0$.

If you are more interested in questions surrounding exponentiation, logarithms, and the such, you might check out this recent [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118523/is-pi-log-ab-for-some-integers-a-b-1) in a similar spirit.

Answer (score 0):

Also   [Rationals are dense in Reals](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Rationals_Dense_in_Reals) and  [Irrationals are dense in reals](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Irrationals_Dense_in_Reals)

which implies that you

1. can always find a sequence of   irrational numbers that converges to a given rational
2. can always find a sequence of      rational numbers that converges to a given irrational