# Use the unique factorization for integers theorem and the definition of logarithm to prove that $\log_3 (7)$ is irrational.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms

Use the unique factorization for integers theorem and the definition of logarithms to prove that $\log_3 (7)$ is irrational.

> I am taking a beginners fundamental mathematics module, no advanced stuff please. Thanks!

My attempt.

Suppose for a contradiction that it is rational, that is $\log_3(7)=\frac{a}{b}$ for some $a,b\in R$ where $b\neq0$. Therefore, by the definition of logarithms, $7=3^{\frac{a}{b}}$. By the theorem of unique factorization, $7=1*7$ is unique.

Ok I'm plain stuck! Any help please?

Comment: If $7=3^{a/b}$ we have $7^b=3^a$, that is a contradiction by the UFT, since $3$ and $7$ and different primes.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Make this an answer.

Comment: Awesome thanks yeah that.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/9144/7850) is a more general result

Comment: In your beginning of solution, it should be "for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. We get $7^b=3^a$. Without loss of generality $b\gt 0$. Then $a\gt 0$, else $3^a$ is too small. Finally, can use Unique Factorization, or the fact that the prime $7$ divides $7^b$, so $7$ divides $3^a$. But if a prime divides a product it divides one of the terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that
$$\log_3(7)=\frac{a}{b} \iff b\log(7)=a\log(3) \iff \log(7^b)=\log(3^a) \iff 7^b=3^a ,$$
contradiction.

Comment: This is precisely the answer Jack provided in the comments.  You should give Jack a few hours to post his comments as an answer.