# Power of two startiing with any desired sequence of digits

Tags: prime-numbers

I heard from a video that there is a theorem that proves that exists a power of two wghose leading or last digits can be any sequence of digits for example your telephone number. Can anyone point me to this theorem please?

Comment: Not the last digits! For instance, the last digit must always be $2,4,6$, or $8$.

Answer (score 1):

You can stipulate the leading decimal digits of a number $n$ by setting limits on the fractional part of $\log_{10}n$. For instance, the leading digits of $n$ are $142857$ if

$\lfloor\log_{10}142857\rfloor \le \lfloor\log_{10}n\rfloor < \lfloor\log_{10}142858\rfloor$

To find an integer $k$ such that the leading digits of $2^k$ are $142857$, we want

$\lfloor\log_{10}142857\rfloor \le \lfloor k\log_{10}2\rfloor < \lfloor\log_{10}142858\rfloor$

$\log_{10}2$ is irrational (see e.g. [this StackExchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/9144/1508)), so such a $k$ always exists $-$ see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Equidistribution_modulo_1).

Comment: ha, beat me to it! :)